How take input while "message"/r in a loop
Hello I am not really sure how to word the title, But I am trying to build a blockchain for my first big project and I have 3 threads, a node/miner/wallet. When mining it is constantly printing out the hash (constantly changing) on the same line.

System.out.print(block.hash + "\r");

I would like the user to be able to do transactions from their wallet (requiring input), but it seems like because of the line I've written up above it either ignores input or takes in the hash as input when I press enter. I have tried using a scanner object, doing scanner.nextline(). This is taking in input but because of the hash being repeatedly printed out it is overwriting input the user manually puts in with the current hash.
// BLOCK CLASS mine method
public void mineBlock(){
        nonce++;
        hash = calHash();
        currentHashValue = new BigInteger(hash,16);
}


 // MINER CLASS minemethod
public void mineBlock(Block block) {
        System.out.println("mining block at index: " + block.blockNumber + ", at difficulty: " + block.getDifficulty() + "... ");
        while (!block.isHashFound(block.currentHashValue)) {
            block.mineBlock();
           // System.out.print(block.hash + "\r");

        }
        System.out.println("Nice you've mined a block: " + block.hash);
    }


// TEST INPUT CLASS
public class test implements Runnable{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("please input something");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("you have inputted: " + input);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Transaction> linkedQueueToMiner = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Transaction>();

        Thread miner = new Thread(new Miner(linkedQueueToMiner));
        Thread wallet = new Thread(new Wallet(linkedQueueToMiner));
        Thread node = new Thread(new Node(linkedQueueToMiner));
        Thread test = new Thread(new test());

        node.start();
        wallet.start();
        miner.start();
        test.start();


    }
}

Here I am trying to input "a" but it does not print it out,
please input something
mining block at index: 20, at difficulty: 776499968... 
5f15dd7faa
you have inputted: 
6d27ec1231153bdc
0ba3c8f36044
d3ce

When I do this it doesn't work, but when I remove the
System.out.print(block.hash + "\r");

It works perfectly fine
please input something
mining block at index: 20, at difficulty: 776499968... 
aaaaaaaa
you have inputted: aaaaaaaa

The miner is not pausing/waiting at all while the test class is waiting for input here. The bottom output works but I would like the user to see the hashes changing as the miner is looping trying to get the correct hash.
